# Order PHP array by value

Tags: php, arrays

I need to reorder this array by the 'score' value (descending)

```
array
  21 => 
    array
      'score' => int 2
  23 => 
    array
      'score' => int 3
  26 => 
    array
      'score' => int 5
```

Any advice on how to go about this would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out uasort - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

```
<?php

$array = array(
  21 => 
    array(
      'score' => 2 ),
  23 => 
    array(
      'score' => 3 ),
  26 => 
    array( 
      'score' => 5 ) );

var_dump( $array );

uasort( $array, mysort );

var_dump( $array );

function mysort($a, $b)
{
    if ($a[ 'score' ] == $b[ 'score' ]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a[ 'score' ] < $b[ 'score' ]) ? 1 : -1;
}
?>
```